# Handling round screen on regular Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a smartwatch with round screen that is running regular Android 5.1 (not Android Wear).

My layout is getting cut off on the sides and would like to adjust it so everything fits on the screen or make a separate layout.

Is there a way to achieve this on regular Android? I've been reading up, but all the solutions require Android Wear APIs.

Comment: This app needs to run on other devices too?

Comment: It's meant for a specific square Android smartwatch and it works fine there. But now it has to run on a round screen.
No phones or tablets.